# Set available processors in Executors.newFixedThreadPool in HTTPServer

Tags: java, multithreading, httpserver, executors

I'm building an HTTPServer that needs to handle multiple requests at the same time.

The main function of what I built looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/", new MyRequestDispatcher());

    server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    server.start();
}
```

Now I'm thinking on how this `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` works regarding the number of threads created. As I have read that the number of threads to be created is not limited, if I get a thousand of requests at the same time, would it create a thousand of threads?

I'm thinking on limiting the number of threads created at the same time in order to be handled properly in the machine where it is being run. I thought on something like this:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

The goal is to only create the given number of threads depending on the available processors in the system.

Would this work?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can, but it's not necessarily optimal if the threads do anything that blocks - if you have more threads, you can be doing work while the blocked ones are waiting. You can always set a limit on the number of threads in the cached-like thread pool - look at the implementation of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` vs `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I will have a look into them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work, and it's what you'll see recommended most often.

Depending on your specific use-case you still may want to use a different number.

- If your tasks are blocking (e.g. because of I/O operations), you may benefit from more threads than available cores.
- If you can run multiple hardware threads per core, you may also benefit from more threads than available cores. For example, Intel x86 Xeons with Hyperthreading enabled can run 2 threads per core, IBM POWER8 and Oracle SPARC M7 - up to 8 threads per core.
- If you are running concurrent GC collectors, you experience significant GC pressure, and you have a non-stop running thread pool, you may find that slightly decreasing the number of threads in the pool can move you in a sweeter spot. This is a fairly specific example, though, which I'm mentioning because it was a big revelation in the system I'm currently working on.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar,
what do you think then if I want to code it to have "the best" performance in average when running in any machine? If I don't know the specs do you think that the executor I set in the example above would be the best approach to follow?

Comment: Short answer: *Yes*. Long answer: At that level of detail (none), even this rational rule of thumb is highly speculative. You don't expect that the best gift for a friend's birthday is the top selection in a "Best wedding and birthday gifts" Internet survey, right? Nevertheless, more often than not, `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` as the size of your thread pool is not your real problem. If it is, you'll need to prove it, then root cause it, then find a solution - and this is the topic of another discussion :)